Elementary number theory problem on factors and divisibility

Problem 1.12.12 (All Russian Olympiad 2017 Day 1 Grade 10 P5). Suppose $n$ is a composite positive integer. Let $1<a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_k<n$ be all the divisors of $n$. It is known that $a_1+1$, $\ldots$, $a_k+1$ are all divisors of some $m$ (except $1$, $m$). Find all such $n$.

The book says to divide the problem into two cases, when number of factors of $n$ is $3$ and when number of factors of $n$ is $\ge4$, but I cannot really figure it out.

"For some $m$" doesn't make sense, as no $m$ has been introduced. Typo? Bad translation?

@GerryMyerson Yes, the wording of the question is pretty bad. I just took m to be a natural number that has factors 1,a1+1..,ak+1 ,m.

Please put the math into the post itself using MathJax, rather than an image that can't be searched or edited.

Edit your question and add your attempts otherwise this question will get downvotes and close votes.

So it sounds like what you are saying is, "we also suppose there is a positive integer $m$ such that $1,a_1+1,a_2+1,\dotsb,a_k+1,m$ is the complete set of divisors of $m$."

@~"...is the complete set..." : except for the specific divisors $~1~$ and $~m.$

If $k=3$, then $n=p^4$, where $p$ is prime. Thus all factors of $m$ are $1,p+1,p^2+1,p^3+1,m$, so we have $(p+1)(p^3+1)=(p^2+1)^2$. This is impossible.
If $k\geq 4$, then we have
$$a_1a_k=a_2a_{k-1}=n$$
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_k)=(1+a_2)(1+a_{k-1})=m$$
This is also impossible.

why is the latter "$$(1+a_1)(1+a_k)=(1+a_2)(1+a_{k-1})=m$$" impossible?

We're supposed to have $a_k<n$, so in the case $k=3$ I don't think we're supposed to take $p^2+1$ to be a factor of $m$. But the problem is badly stated, so who knows?

These two equalities tell us $a_1+a_k=a_2+a_{k-1}$ and $a_1a_k=a_2a_{k-1}$, which implies $a_1=a_2,a_{k-1}=a_{k}$.

@DJWCB ok thanks
